# Vue.js & TypeScript type-check templates in Webstorm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur

Is it possible to type-check Vue templates in Webstorm like in Visual Studio Code via Vetur?
[Vetur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl6K4.png)